# How to retrieve table of groups of related nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a dataset in neo4j that looks something like this:

```
(a)-[similar_to]->(b)
```

Each node has a property called 'id' that is unique.  In the following example dataset, each 'a' node had a 'similar_to' relationship to each 'b' node:

```
a.id  b.id
1     5
1     2
2     13
3     12
```

Here is what the topology looks like:

[graph topology image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8odg0kdwbp3wuhd/topology.png)

What I would like to do is to retrieve a table of the two groups of nodes that are connected such that the result would look like:

```
1, 2, 5, 13
3, 12
```

The best I've been able to do with Cypher so far is:

```
MATCH (a)-[r:similar_to*]-(b)
RETURN collect(distinct a.id)
```

However, the output of this is to print all of the nodes on one row:

```
5, 1, 2, 3, 12, 13
```

I have tried various permutations of this query, but keep failing. I've searched the forums for 'subgraph' and 'neo4j', but was unable to find a suitable solution.  Any direction/ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is you want every root node "a" and the group of all nodes that have the direct/indirect relationships [:similar_to] with the "a", if so, try this,

```
MATCH (a)-[r:similar_to*]->(b)
Where not(a<-[:similar_to]-())
RETURN a, collect(distinct b.id) as group
```

The "WHERE" clause restricts the node "a" to be the root node of each group.
The "RETURN" clause groups all nodes on the matched paths by the root node "a".

If you want to include each root "a" in the group, just change the path to,

```
(a)-[r:similar_to*0..]->(b)
```